# Как правильно записать функцию чтения в буффер на с, c++

Tags: c++, буферизация

Считать конкретное количество данных проблем нет. Размер данных, которые могут прийти не может быть больше чем buf_len. Но он может быть меньше. Как в этом случае правильно организовать выход из цикла и узнать что считали все пришедшие данные. То есть куда лучше вставить *return buf_len;*? При второй итерации в цикле read вернет ноль или EAGAIN, если мы считали все данные при первом проходе?

```
int full_read(int fd, char *buf, size_t buf_len, size_t retry_number = 50)
{
    int SUCCESS          = -1;
    int current_errno    = 0;
    size_t counter_reply = retry_number + 1;
    ssize_t count_rb     = 0;
    do
    {
        count_rb = read(fd, buf, buf_len);
        if (count_rb == -1)
        {
            current_errno = errno;
            if (EINTR == current_errno)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if ( EAGAIN == current_errno) //not data
            {
                SUCCESS = 0;
                return SUCCESS;
            }
            else //unknown error
            {
                std::cerr << "Error read";
                throw "Error read";
            }
        }
        buf_len -= count_rb;
        buf     += count_rb;
        --counter_reply;
    }
    while (counter_reply && buf_len);
    throw "Error read reply";
}
```

Comment: если чтение возвращает 0, значит сокет закрыт.
Возвращайте не одно, а два значения из функции (через указатель или возвращать структурой) и будет Вам счастье

Comment: @KoVadim, функция будет применяться не только для сокета, а еще и для устройства. И мне необходимо разместить return buf_len в full_read. А вот что вернет full_read не столь важно.

Comment: В сдучае если данных нет, то если сокет блокирующий, он не должен возвращать 0 (кроме закрытия). Он должен ждать хотя бы одного байта или сигнала. Если сокет неблокирующий, он возвращает EAGAIN. Делайте так, что бы Ваше устройство работало также и будет хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim, правильно ли я понимаю, что если на второй итерации в цикле я получаю EAGAIN, т.к. считали всё в первой итерации, то это означает что считали все данные? Всё работает в неблоикрующем режиме.

Comment: EAGAIN значит что на данный момент больше данных нет. (дословно переводиться как "пробуй ещё")